# Функции "mod", "div"

Tags: pascal

Помогите разобраться с Паскалем. Вот я сделал начало программы и сказали, чтобы закончить её, нужно розобраться с "mod", "div" помогите, пожалуйста... Вот то, что я сделал:

```
Program mass;
Uses crt;
var A:array [1..100] of integer;
i,n,m:integer;
begin
     clrscr;
     writeln('введіть кількість елементів масивів');
     read(n);
     for i:=1 to n do
         begin
              A[i]:=random(101)-60;
              write(A[i],' ');
         end;
     writeln;
     m:=0;
     for i:=1 to n do
     if A[i]<0 then begin
                         m:=i;
                         break;
                    end;

write(A[m],' ','його порядковий номер = ',m);
readkey;
end.
```

Вот условие:

> Среди элементов массива, которые размещены после его первого отрицательного элемента, найти количество таких, которые заканчиваются не больше за 5. Буду благодарен.

Comment: я из Днепропетровска, украинский знаю отлично, но в смысл этой хрени " не больше за 5" я все равно въехать не могу...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно поняла, то последняя цифра не больше 5 должна быть. А то в Украине трудности с русским.

```
for i:=m+1 to n do
    if a[i] mod 10 <=5 then writeln(a[i]);
```

Comment: проблемы не в Украине, а на Украине. Тем более, что даже на Украине их нет-проблемы у автора темы.